# Can you still use "epic" in a non-"epic" way?

Tags: meaning, slang, semantic-shift

The semantic shift of *epic* from denoting something related with heroism, grandeur, etc. to meaning something more akin to *awesome* or *impressive* [is well-attested](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26231/173942). However, how much is [its older meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_(genre)) still largely accepted? — For example,

> The plot of *Interstellar* is more epic than that of *Gravity*.

could mean

1. The plot of *Interstellar* is more awesome than that of *Gravity*.
2. The plot of *Interstellar* has more elements akin to epic poetry that of *Gravity* does.

However, even for me, the sentence above seems at first to have the meaning of example 1. If I say the sentence aloud (with relatively flat intonation), however, the meaning shifts more towards example 2; Only if I have a particular tone (an "that was totally awesome!" type of tone) does example 1 still come up. Does this mean that the second meaning is no longer largely accepted, or am I just spending too much time online?

Comment: Yes. It only depends on your audience

Comment: Of course [*awesome* underwent a similar shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6802/48571), to the meaning you use.

Comment: @Unrelated yes, just like you can use "terrible" to mean "awe-inspiring"... If you're talking to someone who was born a couple hundred years ago.

Comment: @errantlinguist True, and you can use "epic" and all your philistine friends will think you're on a long-expired drug trip